# In Java 8, whats an elegant way to remove certain duplicate words from a string

Tags: java, regex, string, java-8

What's an elegant way in Java 8 to remove **certain specific** duplicate words from a string such that:

With a list of non-duplicate words: **[cat, mat]**

Given a String: *"A cat sat on a mat and wore a hat A **cat** sat on a **mat** and wore a hat"*

The result should be: *"A cat sat on a mat and wore a hat A sat on a and wore a hat"*

**NOTE:** Its the first occurrence we want to preserve.

Comment: [Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: `Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(string.split(" ")));` [A, cat, sat, on, a, mat, and, wore, hat]

Comment: should the words to remove be the lasts or can it be firsts

Comment: @DmitryZagorulkin But that also filters the duplicate `hat`, which is not desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this:

```
String input = "A cat sat on a mat and wore a hat A cat sat on a mat and wore a hat";

Set<String> toFilter = Set.of("cat", "mat"); // Java 9's set.of, for brievety.
Set<String> seen = new HashSet<>();

String result = Arrays.stream(input.split(" "))
        .filter(s -> !toFilter.contains(s) || seen.add(s))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

System.out.println(result); // A cat sat on a mat and wore a hat A sat on a and wore a hat
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `seen.add` will return false if the word was already in the set.

---

As a response to some of the comments, worrying about the order of the words not being preserved:

The documentation for [`Arrays.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-) doesn't explicitly say the returned stream is ordered, but it does mention:

> Returns a sequential Stream with the specified array as its source.

An array has a defined ordering to it, i.e. it is ordered, so I'd say it's safe to read this as that the returned stream is also ordered.

Another way you can get an ordered stream is by using `Arrays.spliterator` and wrapping the result in a stream yourself (since the spliterator will report `ORDERED` by [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#spliterator-T:A-)):

```
StreamSupport.stream(Arrays.spliterator(input.split(" ")), false)
```

But currently, `Arrays.stream` does this too.

---

Otherwise, there is always the for-loop fall back:

```
String[] tokens = input.split(" ");
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(" ");
for(String s : tokens) {
    if(!toFilter.contains(s) || seen.add(s)) {
        joiner.add(s);
    }
}

String result = joiner.toString();
```

Comment: But this doesn't ensure the order objects after filter

Comment: @pvpkiran @tobias_k Afaik a stream created from a list or array is always ordered by default. If you inspect the characteristics of the underlying spliterator, it has `ORDERED` there. This falls apart when you go parallel though.

Answer (score 3):

Updated [Here](https://regex101.com/r/AMMx4H/2) an example using a positive lookahead, the words removed are the firsts to occur

```
\b(cat|mat)\b(?=.*\b\1\b)
```

in java

```
String input = "A cat sat on a mat and wore a hat A cat sat on a mat and wore a hat";
input = input.replaceAll("\\b(cat|mat)\\b(?=.*\\b\\1\\b)", "");
System.out.println( input );
```

Comment: the correct answer with only one regex needs lookbehind with variable size match which doesn't exist

Comment: You should include a space with the word too, otherwise it leaves two spaces (i.e. the one before and after the word).

Comment: Now it removes first occurrence not last

Comment: @anubhava, not only the first but all except the last, but i ask to OP if it's requiered otherwise the string should be reversed

Answer (score 3):

For a more basic solution than the others;

```
String input = "A cat sat on a mat and wore a hat A cat sat on a mat and wore a hat";
String[] list = {"cat", "mat"};
    for(String word : list){
        int index = input.indexOf(word) + word.length();
        input = input.substring(0, index) + input.substring(index).replace(word, "");
    }
```

Or by utilising the 'limit' parameter on `String.split()` you could replace the loop above with the following;

```
    for(String word : list){
        String[] split = input.split(word, 2);
        input = split[0] + word + split[1].replace(word, "");
    }
```

Both of these output `A cat sat on a mat and wore a hat A  sat on a  and wore a hat` but if you wanted to remove the double space you could easily call `input.replaceAll(" {2,}", " ");` before returning the value to remove any additional spaces.